# Constructing tuple of value from tuple of reference, with one-argument templated constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I have a tuple of const references `std::tuple<const Matrix&, ...>` from which I construct a tuple of values `std::tuple<Matrix, ...>`. For any size of tuple greater than 1, this works fine: (online example: https://godbolt.org/g/24E8tU)

```
#include <tuple>

struct Matrix {
    Matrix() = default;
    Matrix(Matrix const&) = default;

    template <typename T>
    explicit Matrix(T const&) {
        // in reality, this comes from Eigen, and there is real work
        // being done here. this is just to demonstrate that the code
        // below fails
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "!");
    }
};

void works() {
    Matrix m1, m2;
    std::tuple<const Matrix &, const Matrix &> tuple_of_ref{m1, m2};

    std::tuple<Matrix, Matrix> t{tuple_of_ref};
}
```

However, for a tuple of size 1, this code fails to compile:

```
void fails() {
    Matrix m;
    std::tuple<const Matrix &> tuple_of_ref{m};

    // Tries and fails to instantiate Matrix(std::tuple<const Matrix &>)
    std::tuple<Matrix> t{tuple_of_ref};
}
```

Note the `Matrix` class has a templated constructor which accepts `std::tuple`.

> ```
> template<typename T>
> explicit Matrix(const T& x)
> ```

I don't want to use this constructor, and I can't change it since it's third-party code.

I think my `works()` example properly calls the constructor listed as #4 on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple):

> ```
> template< class... UTypes >
> tuple( const tuple<UTypes...>& other );
> ```
>
> 4) Converting copy-constructor. For all i in `sizeof...(UTypes)`, initializes ith element of the tuple with `std::get<i>(other)`.

The `fails()` example tries to use [this constructor](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/tuple#L657), presumably #3, which I don't want:

> ```
> template< class... UTypes >
> explicit tuple( UTypes&&... args );
> ```
>
> 3) Converting constructor. Initializes each element of the tuple with the corresponding value in `std::forward<Utypes>(args)`.

How can I make sure `tuple`'s constructor #4 is used for both cases? My real use case is inside a variadic template so I don't know the size of the tuple in advance.

Comment: Your problem is independent of Eigen. If you take one more step and reproduce your problem with an example people can pop into a compiler and reproduce for themselves, you're likely to get more answers because we can get started faster. Bonus points if you use an online compiler we can edit in-place at

Comment: https://ideone.com/5I8acU Ideone with a minimal reproducible example  for us to work with

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added a link to godbolt. Here is a modified example without Eigen https://godbolt.org/g/MDG4qU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, so... this is the problem:

```
template<typename T>
explicit Matrix(const T& x)
```

That is a really unfriendly constructor - because it's lying. `Matrix` isn't actually constructible from *anything*, just some specific things - but there's no way to externally detect what those things are.

When considering what how to construct a `tuple<Matrix>` from a `tuple<Matrix const&>`, we have [lots of choices](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple), but actually only two are viable:

```
// #2, with Types... = {Matrix}
tuple(Matrix const&);

// #3, with UTypes = {tuple<Matrix const&>&}
tuple(tuple<Matrix const&>&);
```

Both end up trying to construct a `Matrix` from a `tuple<Matrix const&>`, which doesn't work and you're stuck.

---

Now, you might think that #4 was your salvation here - generating a constructor that is:

```
tuple(tuple<Matrix const&> const& );
```

And constructing its underlying `Matrix` from the `tuple` argument's underlying `Matrix`. That is, using the converting copy constructor. It seems like the problem is that this constructor works but that #3 is preferred for whatever reason (i.e. that it takes a less cv-qualified reference) and that the solution is to try to fiddle with the arguments so that #4 is preferred (i.e. by using `as_const()` on the argument).

But that constructor isn't less preferred... it's actually *not viable* here because the restriction on [that constructor is](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple.cnstr#16.3) (from [LWG 2549](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2549)):

> either `sizeof...(Types) != 1`, or (when `Types...` expands to `T` and `UTypes...` expands to `U`) `is_­convertible_­v<const tuple<U>&, T>`, `is_constructible_­v<T, const tuple<U>&>`, and `is_­same_­v<T, U>` are all `false`.

But we do have `sizeof..(Types) == 1` and those things are not all false (in particular, the second one is true - which is the source of all your problems to begin with), so #4 is simply not a candidate and there isn't really a neat trick to just make it one.

---

So, how to fix it? The best thing **by far** to do would to be fix `Matrix`. I realize that probably isn't likely, but it has to be said.

You could wrap `Matrix` in something that actually adds constraints to its constructor to avoid this problem. Since you're already copying it into a `tuple`, that gives you the opportunity to do something even as simple as:

```
template <typename T>
struct only_copyable {
    only_copyable(only_copyable const& ) = default;
    only_copyable(T const& t) : t(t) { }
    template <typename U> only_copyable(U const& ) = delete;
    T t;
};
```

but you probably want something little more realistic than this. Also your type could just inherit from `Matrix` and just fiddle with its constructors for sanity's sake.

Or, when dealing specifically with `tuple`s of size 1, you could avoid using the tuple constructor and just default construct/assign. Or explicitly call `get<0>` or things of that sort.

Or, you could just avoid `tuple`s of size 1 entirely. Which is a weirdly specific thing to do, but maybe that's enough (or you could wrap `tuple` in such a way that `my_tuple<A, B, C...>` is `tuple<A,B,C...>` but `my_tuple<A>` is really `tuple<A, monostate>`).

But really... fixing the `Matrix` constructor seems just super worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for finding the LWG issue. I noticed that restriction was not there in C++14 standard, which is probably why the code worked for me before with an older compiler. A more general question: is the change retroactive to C++11?  Should this be considered a compiler (or stdlib) bug because it breaks existing code compiled with `-std=c++11`, or is this a normal thing for compilers to do because it is fixing a defect?

Comment: @Lack I wouldn't think this is a compiler bug. Defects tend to get applied retroactively, given that they are defects. I don't know what the hard and fast rule here is.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked but... what about passing through a intermediate template function `tplHelper()` that, in the more generic case, simply return the value received

```
template <typename T>
T tplHelper (T const & tpl)
 { return tpl; }
```

but in case of a `std::tuple` with a single type return the contained value ?

```
template <typename T>
T tplHelper (std::tuple<T> const & tpl)
 { return std::get<0>(tpl); }
```

If you create `t` passing through `tplHelper()`

```
std::tuple<Matrix, Matrix> t{ tplHelper(tuple_of_ref) };

// ...

std::tuple<Matrix> t{ tplHelper(tuple_of_ref) };
```

when you have two or mote types, you continue to call the copy constructor of `std::tuple`, but when you call it with a tuple with a single matrix, you avoid the template `Matrix` constructor and call the copy `Matrix` constructor.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <tuple>

struct Matrix
 {
   Matrix ()
    { }

   template <typename T>
   explicit Matrix (const T &)
    {
      // This constructor fails to compile when T is std::tuple<...>
      // and I don't want to use it at all
      static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "!");
    }
 };

template <typename T>
T tplHelper (T const & tpl)
 { return tpl; }

template <typename T>
T tplHelper (std::tuple<T> const & tpl)
 { return std::get<0>(tpl); }

void m2 ()
 {
    Matrix m1, m2;

    std::tuple<const Matrix &, const Matrix &> tuple_of_ref{m1, m2};

    std::tuple<Matrix, Matrix> t{ tplHelper(tuple_of_ref) };
 }

void m1 ()
 {
   Matrix m;

   std::tuple<const Matrix &> tuple_of_ref{m};

   // now compile!
   std::tuple<Matrix> t{ tplHelper(tuple_of_ref) };
 }


int main ()
 {
   m2();
   m1();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd circumvent this issue by calling `std::get` on the "source" tuple:

```
Thing thing;
std::tuple<Thing const &> get_source{thing};
std::tuple<Thing> get_target{std::get<0>(get_source)};
```

This avoids calling the explicit constructor and instead calls the copy constructor.

In order to generalize this for tuples of any length you can make use of [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and what builds upon it and wrap this all up in a function:

```
template<typename T>
using no_ref_cv = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;

template<typename... T, std::size_t... Idx>
auto MakeTupleWithCopies_impl(std::tuple<T...> const & source, std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
  return std::tuple<no_ref_cv<T>...>{std::get<Idx>(source)...};
}

template<typename... T>
auto MakeTupleWithCopies(std::tuple<T...> const & source) {
  return MakeTupleWithCopies_impl(source, std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
}
```

***Stuck with C++11?***

`std::integer_sequence` and it's friends can be written in C++11, too (not a full replacement, misses member function for example and probably breaks with `signed` integer types):

```
template<typename T, T...>
struct integer_sequence {};

template<std::size_t... Ints>
using index_sequence = integer_sequence<std::size_t, Ints...>;


template<typename T, T... t>
integer_sequence<T, t..., sizeof...(t)> inc(integer_sequence<T, t...>) {
    return {};
}

template<typename T, T N, std::size_t Count>
struct make_integer_sequence_help {
    using type = decltype(inc(typename make_integer_sequence_help<T,N,Count - 1>::type{}));
};

template<typename T, T N>
struct make_integer_sequence_help<T, N, 0> {
    using type = integer_sequence<T>;
};

template<class T, T N>
using make_integer_sequence = typename make_integer_sequence_help<T,N, N>::type;


template<std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>;

template<class... T>
using index_sequence_for = make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>;
```

Then you only need to change the `auto` return type specifications of the two functions to `std::tuple<no_ref_cv<T>...>`.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the other answer for the full explanation referring to the standard, but realistically using `std::get` is probably the simplest solution. (It just requires making a partial specialization of my variadic template for the case size==1.)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't think of a good solution to the problem without effectively reimplementing the `tuple` constructor you wanted to be invoked:

```
struct TupleFromTuple{};

template<class... T, class... U>
struct TupleFromTuple<std::tuple<T...>, std::tuple<U...>>
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(T) == sizeof...(U), "Tuples should be the same size");
    using to_t = std::tuple<T...>;
    using from_t = std::tuple<U...>;
    static to_t Apply(from_t& tup)
    {
        return ApplyImpl(tup, std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
    }
private:
    template<size_t... I>
    static to_t ApplyImpl(from_t& tup, std::index_sequence<I...>){
        return {std::get<I>(tup)...};
    }
};
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0yejbhRAN4xvwIrO)

Uses some light C++14, but nothing that you cannot implement in C++11

Effectively we use index sequences to call `std::get` ourselves. 
Given some garbage implementation of `Matrix` like so:

```
struct Matrix
{
    Matrix() = default;
    template<class T>
    explicit Matrix(const T& foo){foo.fail();}
};
```

Your `fails` test now passes:

```
void fails() {
    Matrix m;
    std::tuple<const Matrix &> tuple_of_ref{m};
    auto t = TupleFromTuple<std::tuple<Matrix>, decltype(tuple_of_ref)>::Apply(tuple_of_ref);
}
```